# Knockout JS "uniqueName" binding - Same name to two fields

Tags: knockout.js

I am using Knockout JS to create an editor. I am using the foreach property to loop around a list in my model.

```
 <tbody data-bind='foreach: Properties'>
```

I am using JQuery unobtrusive validation whichneeds a name property to validate. I want to assign the same name to two fields, in order to be able to output a validation message. Is it possible to use the same uniqueName property on two fields?

```
 <tr>
     <td>
         <input data-bind='value: type, uniqueName: true' data-val = "true", data-val-required = "The Type field is required"  /></td>
     </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="UNIQUENAME" data-valmsg-replace="true"></td>
 </tr>
```

Ive copied the example below which shows grid editing and JQuery unobtrusive validation. But i cant work out how to link the validation message with the input field

http://knockoutjs.com/examples/gridEditor.html

Edit:

I am using ASP.NET MVC3 with Razor syntax for the loop input.

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Type", new SelectList(types, "Value", "Text"), "Select", new { data_bind = "value: Type", data_val = "true", data_val_required = "The Type field is required" })
```

I cant figure out how to update the name property. When i add a property using knokcout they all have the same name "**Type**" and the validation doesn't work. They need to be indexed some how Type1 Type2 etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The uniqueName binding just increments an index and sets the name (with a fix for IE).

It looks like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers['uniqueName'] = {
    'init': function (element, valueAccessor) {
        if (valueAccessor()) {
            element.name = "ko_unique_" + (++ko.bindingHandlers['uniqueName'].currentIndex);

            // Workaround IE 6/7 issue
            // - https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/197
            // - http://www.matts411.com/post/setting_the_name_attribute_in_ie_dom/
            if (ko.utils.isIe6 || ko.utils.isIe7)
                element.mergeAttributes(document.createElement("<input name='" + element.name + "'/>"), false);
        }
    }
};
```

So, you can create a custom binding that uses the last index and sets the appropriate attribute

```
ko.bindingHandlers.valmsg = {
    init: function(element) {
        element.setAttribute("data-valmsg-for", "ko_unique_" + ko.bindingHandlers.uniqueName.currentIndex);
    }
};
```

Now, you would just use it like:

```
<tr>
    <td>
         <input data-bind='value: type, uniqueName: true' data-val="true", data-val-required="The Type field is required"  />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td class="field-validation-valid" data-bind="valmsg: true" data-valmsg-replace="true"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: If IE6 or IE7 is used this would always replace the element with a input element?. I use select as well as input fields. My problem is im using ASP.NET MVC3 Razor syntax and i cant figure out how to update the name attribute. Ive updated the question if you can help.

Comment: It doesn't replace it with an `input`, it just merges the attributes.  Will look at your updates.

Comment: Thanks. been at this all day. finally got everything else working apart from this name problem with the validation.

Comment: OK- you can add the `uniqueName` binding and then use the custom `valMsg` binding to add `data-valmsg-for` to the next field.

Comment: Thanks for the example :) I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

A possibly simpler approach derived from [RP-Niemeyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/594420/rp-niemeyer)'s excellent solution:

```
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-bind='attr: {"data-valmsg-for": "ko_unique_" + ko.bindingHandlers.uniqueName.currentIndex}' data-valmsg-replace="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post as a comment, but my reputation is too low...
Thank you very much RP Niemeyer for your post.

I don't know if this has something to do with requirejs and knockout modules, but I had to change

```
ko.bindingHandlers.uniqueName.currentIndex
```

to

```
ko.bindingHandlers.uniqueName.Zb
```

so now I have:

```
define(["knockout"], function(ko) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.valmsg = {
        init: function (element) {
            element.setAttribute("data-valmsg-for", "ko_unique_" + ko.bindingHandlers.uniqueName.Zb);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add a ControlName attribute in the child elements and bind the input name to this and the data-valms-for too

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" data-bind="value: myValue, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', attr: {ControlName}" required /> 
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-bind='attr: {"data-valmsg-for":ControlName}' data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```