# how to specify the name property using knockout js

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I have a bound list using knockoutjs / mvc3

```
<div data-bind="foreach: phones">
   <input data-bind='value: number' />
</div>
```

to send this to my controller action which is

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index([Deserialize] WizardModel wizard, IStepViewModel step)
{
}
```

Previously I was able to bind to my List< T > using Jquery by specifying the name on the input which would be

```
 <input name="Phones[0].Name"
              Phones[1].Number etc..
```

But I'm now im using knockout I'm not clear how this should work. Anyone steer me in the right direction.

Ta

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can do this using the attr binding in a template or foreach like this assuming your phone numbers are in an observable array.

```
<input data-bind='attr: { name: "Phones["+$index()+"].Name"}' />
```

Im also assuming you are using the latest version of knockout so you can use the $index.

This will allow you to name the inputs so they work with MVC model binding.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That looks great.. when i inspect the input its exactly as you have here.. no change to $index. I have v2.1.0 from fresh clone - is that the right version?

Comment: Yes its in 2.1.0. There were a couple of typos in my answer which Ive now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'uniqueName', build in knockout. Here is the documentation:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/uniqueName-binding.html

If you want custom binding(for instance unique id generation) you can use custom binding: 
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

These are usefull answers for unuqueName and uniqueId:
[Unique ids in knockout.js templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233176/unique-ids-in-knockout-js-templates) and
[Knockout JS "uniqueName" binding - Same name to two fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758832/knockout-js-uniquename-binding-same-name-to-two-fields)

My implementation for unique id generation is:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.uniqueId = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        if (valueAccessor()) {
            element.id = ko.bindingHandlers.uniqueId.prefix + (++ko.bindingHandlers.uniqueId.counter);
        }
    },
    counter: 0,
    prefix: "unique_id_"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could create a custom binding that sets the name attribute. Look here:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

Then you should be able to write:

```
<input data-bind='yourBindingName: Name'  />
```