# knockout js template and validation

Tags: validation, templates, knockout.js

My question is quite simple. 
I use knockout templates for creating grid rows. 
Everything works great. 
The only missing piece is: **How can I validate fields in a template**?
I need to ensure that all the row fields are properly filled when the user ends row editing... 
**I need error messages and field highlight like jquery validation does...**

```
<script id="editTmpl" type="text/html"> 
    <tr data-bind="visible: $data"> 
        <td style="width:50%"> 
            <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: $data.relatedCountryID, select2: { initSelection: $parent.initCountrySelection, multiple: false, allowClear: true, minimumInputLength: 0, width: 'resolve', query: $parent.queryCountries, placeholder: 'Select a country...' }, event: { change: $parent.countrySelectionChange }", style="width: 220px" /> 
        </td> 
        <td style="width:30%"> 
            <input data-bind="value: $data.RateValue" /></td> 
        <td style="width:10%"> 
            <a data-bind="click: $parent.endEditRate" href="#" title="Update"><i class="tableImage ui-icon ui-icon-check"></i></a> 
        </td> 
        <td style="width:10%"> 
            <a data-bind="click: $parent.cancelEditRate" href="#" title="Cancel"><i class="tableImage ui-icon ui-icon-close"></i></a> 
        </td> 
    </tr> 
</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked the Ko.validation plugin https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation?

Comment: I think it will do. Does it operate jQurey validation behind the scenes?

Comment: No, the Ko.validation does not uses jQurey validation. It is a standalone validation library which only dependency is Knockout itself.

Comment: I have found a great solution as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758832/knockout-js-uniquename-binding-same-name-to-two-fields.